# Behaviour defined in eagle when naming a gate like an orientation

Tags: eaglecad, eda

I'm pondering about a possibly undefined behaviour in eagle.

Let's say you have a device named testdevice containing a gate named R90.

If you call

```
ADD testdevice td$1 R90 (1 1);
```

what will happen?

- will the first gate with addlevel next or must be placed rotated by 90°?
- or will the gate R90 be placed without rotation?

If you have a device having two gates R90 and R180 and you issue

```
ADD testdevice td$2 R90 R180 (1 1);
```

will it place

- R90 with 180° rotation or
- R180 with 90° rotation.

When thinking about this problem I see it is a very stupid idea naming gates like possible other parameters, but nevertheless it would be interesting how to formulate a consistent description of eagle's behaviour.

Comment: Try it and see?

Comment: "R90" is a dumb name for a gate in Eagle as that's a way of specifying rotation.  It should still work with proper use of single quotes, but why go out of your way asking for trouble?

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I hoped my question would reveal that I know that it is a dumb name. Nevertheless: I'm not planning to use orientations as a name for gates or other elements. But I'm building an autoplacer for my needs and I want to make sure it works even when dumb gate names arise in a library it encounters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to do what you want is not undocumented at all:

```
help add
```

> The name parameter is the name which the element is to receive in the drawing. If the name could be interpreted as an orientation or option, it must be enclosed in single quotes

Comment: I missed that. Probably because I was looking for rules concerning gate names not drawing elements. But it seems to apply to gates, too.

Answer (score 0):

I found out,

gates with names resembling an orientation will be ignored in an add statement anyway. Or in other words: strings in an ADD-statement which can be read as an orientation will be interpreted as an orientation. If more than one such string are given, the last one will be taken as relevant orientation and the preceding ones will be discarded.

So it is <strike>impossible</strike> (see update below) to place gates with those ambiguous names directly with the ADD command.

Placing them with invoke is possible.

This may be a pitfall, though a rare one.

**Update**:

Tom Carpenters answer brought me onto the hint with the single quotes. Actually if the name of the gate is enclosed in single quotes, it will be recognised as a name rather than an option.

So the following statements will place the gate 'R90' from testdevice:

```
ADD testdevice td$1 'R90' (1 1);
ADD testdevice td$2 'R90' R180 (1 1);
```

The latter one rotating it by 180 degrees.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the gate name in single quotes?

Comment: In the meantime, yes. This works.